# RoR include javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm following the railscast on nested forms https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TG5QIAIutPc
Here they make a javascript function remove_fields

```
function remove_fields(link){
    //this will put the destroy value to true
    $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").value = "1";
    $(link).parent(.field).hide();
}
```

Now as simple as this question may be, I find it hard to make this function available in my project. I've made js file `app/assest/javascripts/remove_fields.js` and this file to my `application.js`

```
//= require remove_fields
```

But it's not working this way. How can I add it properly to my project? (without using the `<script>` tags and without adding it straight into `application.js`)

Comment: What is not working?  Is the file referenced in the rendered HTML?

Comment: Yes, I made a link to it `<%= link_to_function "Delete picture", "remove_fields(this)"%>` 
But when I click it I get an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: remove_fields is not defined`

Comment: I mean, is the `<script src="remove_fields.js">` tag in your html.